# JavaScript: When the `condition` portion of a `ternary` or `if` statement does not include `===` or `>=`

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

In the `condition` portion of the following `ternary` statement, does `playlist.length` equal `playlist.length >= 1` ?

```
var playlist = ["video1", "video2", "video3", "video4", "video5"];

// some code here

alert ((playlist.length) ?
     playlist.length + "video(s) remain in the playlist: " + playlist.join (", ") + "." 
    : "No videos remain in the playlist");
```

---

Likewise, in the following snippet of code, does `! playlist.length` equal `playlist.length === 0` ?

```
alert ((! playlist.length) ?
     "No videos in the playlist."
    : playlist.length + " video(s) remain in the playlist: " + playlist.join(", ") + ".");
```

---

> This is the first time I've seen an example where the `condition` portion of a `ternary` or `if` statement does not include such a notation as `===` or `>=`. So I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: `playlist.length` as a condition will check if that property is undefined or not

Comment: This is very idiomatic. Any boolean value can be used in a ternary/conditional. Since 0 is falsy, `array.length` is `false` when used in such a context

Comment: in your examples it will check for `playlist.length` being zero or not. in general it look for a `truthy` statement.

Comment: It tests if the object it self has a length, i.e data inside of it.

Comment: A zero value will make the condition false, but it reduces readability and consistency of the code. I prefer to use conditions more explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0 is implicitly converted to false in boolean comparisons in JavaScript. So when the length is 0, that is false. Conversely, any other number is implicitly converted to true in boolean comparisons in JavaScript. So when the length is anything but 0 it is true.

An easy test is to use `!!` to see the "truthy" value

`!!1 === true`
`!!0 === false`
`!!6 === true`

Answer (score 1):

The part to the left of the `?` is simply evaluated for "[truthiness](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/116883/is-truthiness-a-legitimate-programming-term)".  The value `0` is "falsy" so evaluates as false for the purposes of the test.  Numeric values other than `0` are "truish" and therefore for this purpose evaluate to true.

All other behaviors of the ternary are the same.

The `===` and `!==` simply add the additional constraint that the L-value and R-value must also be the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The two are very similar: `!playlist.length` and `playlist.length === 0`.

However, they are not exacty the *same*. In fact, here:

```
var playlist1 = [];
var playlist2 = {};
!playlist1.length // true
!playlist2.length // true
playlist1.length === 0 // true
playlist1.length === 0 // false
```

In that sense `!playlist.length` also can be used on all kinds of objects, not just arrays.

In any case, when using this on an array, it is a way to check if the array is empty, and works as you have suggested, the same as `playlist.length === 0`.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript 0 equals false, and any other number value equals true, but if you use === it compare value types too.